# How to Divide the Data into Bins Using Quantiles Using R

Tags: r

Let's say that my summary data is as follows

```
   client_id     order_frequency  order_recency  order_monatery   
   Min.   :  1.0   Min.   : 1.000   Min.   : 0.0   Min.   :   5.48  
   1st Qu.:133.5   1st Qu.: 5.000   1st Qu.:12.0   1st Qu.: 414.14  
   Median :282.0   Median : 8.000   Median :30.0   Median : 761.60  
   Mean   :280.1   Mean   : 8.907   Mean   :33.6   Mean   : 880.08  
   3rd Qu.:423.0   3rd Qu.:12.000   3rd Qu.:51.0   3rd Qu.:1215.03  
   Max.   :560.0   Max.   :32.000   Max.   :89.0   Max.   :3493.15
```

I want to divide this data into bins using the quantiles. Basically im trying to do RFM analysis and this is what I need to do.

```
fr_tbl <- mutate(frm_tbl_initial, frequency_bins = cut(order_frequency, breaks = c())
```

I have this code but I am not sure what to write inside of the breaks. Can someone help me with creating bins using quantiles?

Comment: Did you checkout `binr::bins.quantiles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When desiring to cut a dataset into equal parts (quartiles in this case), the function accepts a single value.  Whereas to cut at specific intervals you define these manually.  In this case you can do:

```
cut(order_frequency, breaks = 4)
```

For example:

```
cut(c(1:100),breaks=4)
```

This creates a factor of values:

```
levels(cut(c(1:100),breaks=4))
```

Where each of the `1:100` values are assigned to one of the q quartile segments according to the 4 levels

Comment: Does cutting into quartiles always means its divided into equal parts?

Comment: Yes, using a single input value (like 4) will cut into equal parts.

Comment: Hmmm, I am not so sure. Try this:
`cut(rnorm(1000), breaks = 4) %>% table()` which results in
`(-4.02,-2.3] (-2.3,-0.588] (-0.588,1.12]   (1.12,2.84] 
           13           247           612           128 `

Comment: Perhaps ambiguity in terms of what's meant by equal parts, but the cut() here has in your example above cut the ranges into (approximately) equal bucket with a range of 1.7.  The actual cut range would be: (abs(-4.02)+2.84)/4 = 1.715 but the results reported in the above example are ranged by the observed values within that cut

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function:

```
bins.quantiles()
```

from the binr package
See more here:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/binr/versions/1.1/topics/bins.quantiles

Answer (score 0):

use.

```
 ntile(order_frequency,n=4)
```

Be careful with cut() because it's very misleading. Cut will break THE RANGE of values into even parts but NOT the data. Therefore if you use cut in a normally distributed variable, the breaks will separate the data into normally distributed groups and not into evenly distributed groups with 25% of the samples each

you can evidence this by looking at the distribution of groups for every function.

```
> table(cut(rnorm(1000),breaks=4,labels=c(1:4)))

  1   2   3   4 
 25 375 526  74 

## try with deciles to make it easier to evidence
> table(cut(rnorm(1000),breaks=10, labels=c(1:10)))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
  2   8  34 137 216 296 195  83  23   6 

> table(ntile(rnorm(1000),n=10))

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

If you want further evidence, you can look at the values of the breakpoints stablished by the function quantile()